# How to register a 64-bit dll (on a 64-bit OS) from a 32-bit application

Tags: delphi, 64-bit

I currently use the following function to register a dll that handles context menu calls.

```
function RegisterLibrary(szLibrary: String): Integer;
var
  hLib: THandle;
  drs: TDllRegisterServer;
begin
  // Attempt to load the library
  hLib := LoadLibrary(PChar(szLibrary));

  // Handle check
  if IsHandle(hLib) then
  begin // Get the register function
    @drs := GetProcAddress(hLib, LIB_REGISTER);

    if Assigned(@drs)
      then Result := drs            // Make the function call
      else Result := GetLastError;  // Return last error

    // Unload the library
    FreeLibrary(hLib);
  end else
    Result := GetLastError; // Return last error
end;
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work when trying to register a 64-bit dll from my 32-bit application.

Is there any alternative to register my 64-bit dll (compiled with free pascal) from my 32-bit application (compiled in Delphi)?

I suppose I can call C:\Windows\system\regsvr32.exe" /s "filename" but would like to know if I have any other alternative.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, a 32 bits process can not load a 64 bit dll. You would have to go with calling a 64 bits process that registers the dll for you.

Comment: Why the down vote? What did I say that was not a correct answer to the question?

Answer (score 4):

You will have to use a 64 bit process to perform the registration, as the 32 bit Delphi program can't load a 64 bit DLL into its address space.

If you don't want to write the code yourself then you can have a look at the [Inno Setup](http://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) source code. There is a Visual Studio project for the 64 bit helper app, and the unit `Helper.pas` has the code to call the external helper, so you can simply use the `HelperRegisterTypeLibrary()` function it contains.